# How to update users with Ajax using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have searched everywhere on this, but all that I could find are tutorials on "**How To Sign In Your Users With Ajax Using Devise**". What I want instead is the way on "**How to properly update users with ajax using Devise**".

So far, I already manage to update the users successfully via Ajax. But, if there are errors, those errors won't be showing. And this is where I need helps.

Here is how the form looks like right now:

[image]

And here are the files associated with this devise forms:

**views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }, remote: true) do |f| %>
            <%= devise_error_messages! %>

            <% if @user.provider.blank? %>
              <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
                <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
                  Current Password
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
                <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
                  New Password
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :required => true %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
                <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
                  Re-type Password
                </label>
                <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :required => true %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>
              </div>              

            <% end %>  

          <% end %>
```

**controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    super
  end

  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path, notice: 'Your details was successfully updated.' 
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

end
```

So my question is how could i modify these so that the flash message will be showing like the picture below via AJAX?

[image]

Comment: could you share your code on github, may be I could take a look at it.

Comment: @Saad hey sure, this is the link: https://github.com/ryzalyusoff/quickrails2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Omkar, I am managed to solve this problem. I changed a few things though in order to make it works perfectly. Here are my updated codes:

**controllers/registrations_controller.rb:**

```
  def update
    # For Rails 4
    account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)

    @update = update_resource(@user, account_update_params)
    if @update 
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**views/devise/registrations/update.js.erb:**

```
<% if @update %>
  window.location.replace('<%= edit_user_registration_path %>');
<% else %>

  <% if @user.errors.messages.size > 0 %>
    <% @user.errors.each do |attr,err| %>
        $('#js-error-block').append('<%= attr %> <%= err %> <br/>');  
        $('.alert').show(); 
    <% end %>
  <% end %> 

<% end %>
```

**views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }, remote: true) do |f| %>         
  <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;">
    <div id='js-error-block'></div>
  </div>          

  <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
    <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
      Current Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", :required => true  %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
    <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
      New Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :required => true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row row-condensed space-4">
    <label class="col-sm-3" for="user_first_name">
      Re-type Password
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-9 form-group">
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", :class => "form-control", :required => true %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>
  </div>              
<% end %>
```

**CHANGES:**

1. Instead of using `update_attributes(account_update_params)` directly, I use `update_resource(@user, account_update_params)` and assign it to @update variable. Otherwhise, error with "Unknown attribute 'current_password'" will comes out
2. Instead of checking for @user.valid?, I check if @update is success
3. Instead of using `<%= devise_error_messages! %>`, i loop through the @users error, and display it accordingly. You can refer more about this here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M001905

Answer (score 1):

```
def update
  # For Rails 4
  account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)

  # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank
  if account_update_params[:password].blank?
    account_update_params.delete("password")
    account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
  end

  @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
    # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case their password changed
    sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end

end
```

views/devise/registrations/update.**js**.erb:

```
<% if @user.valid? %>
  # Redirect To path
  window.location.replace('<%= edit_user_registration_path %>');
<% else %>
  # Show Errors
  $('#js-error-block').html('<%= devise_error_messages! %>');
<% end %>
```

views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:

In edit.html.erb add div to update DOM using javascript.

```
<div id='js-error-block'></div>
```

**Flow:**

1. User Submits form (remote: true)
2. update action will get called
3. since request is JS request. update.js.erb will get rendered in response.
4. update.js.erb will have code to update DOM or in simple language to update edit.html.erb page.

For More information you can refer this rails cast:

[#136 jQuery & Ajax (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised)